# Jquery selectors by CSS class in IE is really slow--workarounds?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, css-selectors

I have a web app where I have several elements with `class="classA"`. I want to select and apply a function to all of them. I am doing the obvious thing, which is `$(".classA").each(function () { ... })`. This works just fine in Chrome/Safari/Firefox but is really slow in IE. It turns out IE has serious performance issues when selecting things by CSS class in jQuery.

I was wondering if anyone has suggestions on good ways to deal with this. I can't use ID selectors because there can be multiple DOM elements I want to select.

-- EDIT --

Below is my tests code.

- test1 uses `document.getElementById("id")` and is very fast.
- test2 uses `$("#id")` and is pretty slow.
- test3 uses `$(".class")` and is even slower.

As far as I can tell, there is no native implementation of document.getElementsByClassName in IE8--I get an error when I try to use it.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">


            function test1 ()
            {
                var start = (new Date).getTime();
                for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                {
                    document.getElementById("test1");
                }
                var elapsed = (new Date).getTime() - start;
                alert("test1 elapsed: " + elapsed);
            }

            function test2 ()
            {
                var start = (new Date).getTime();
                for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                {
                    var x = $("#test2");
                }
                var elapsed = (new Date).getTime() - start;
                alert("test2 elapsed: " + elapsed);
            }

            function test3 ()
            {
                var start = (new Date).getTime();
                for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                {
                    $(".test3");
                }
                var elapsed = (new Date).getTime() - start;
                alert("test3 elapsed: " + elapsed);
            }

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="test1">test1</div>

        <div id="test2">test2</div>

        <div id="test3" class="test3">test3 1</div>
        <div id="test3" class="test3">test3 2</div>
        <div id="test3" class="test3">test3 3</div>
        <div id="test3" class="test3">test3 4</div>

        <input type="button" onclick="test1();" value="test1" />
        <input type="button" onclick="test2();" value="test2" />
        <input type="button" onclick="test3();" value="test3" />

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the entire function?  It's pretty much a guess otherwise, the expensive part is *inside* that function,

Comment: Its recommended that if your selection based on jQuery becomes to large to work upon you should not look for a client side (javascript) solution for that

Comment: One speed improvement may be to specify the type of tag (assuming they all have the same tag), as in `$("li.classA")` instead of merely `$(".classA")`, for example.

Comment: @Nick - If I'm understanding correctly, I think the item of concern is with the performance of selector against a large number of elements, not the activity of the function itself.

Comment: @patrick - `getElementsByClassName` is a native function though, it should be very fast, even in IE.

Comment: @Nick - My understanding (which may be incorrect) is that `getElementsByClassName` is not implemented in some versions of IE. Time for a little research... :o)

Comment: @patrick - I stand corrected: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#fivemethods I thought it was in IE7+....gg Microsoft.

Comment: @Nick - Thanks for the confirmation and the link. :o)

Comment: @Sam - When doing a benchmark, use valid HTML :) I see `id="test3"` a few times there ;)

Comment: @Nick - heh, my bad, shouldn't affect the results though.

Comment: @Sam - Your test2 would probably be much faster but for the fact that you're creating 10,000 jQuery objects. If you used similar IDs (with a unique suffix, for example), better would be to use a "starts with" selector to get them at once, so you're only creating one jQuery object.

Comment: @Sam - What is your *real* use case here? For example if it's an event handler, `.live()` or `.delegate()` may be the appropriate response, which would bring the startup time for binding handlers down to nil. It would be helpful to know what you're using the results for, there may be a way to greatly reduce or bypass cost there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a variety of things, but IE is optimized to fetch elements by ID, nothing else (it puts elements IDs in a hashtable under the covers).

If you're generating your page via some server-side technology, you could determine the list of elements and then output a JavaScript array of the IDs of those elements, then when the page loads you could loop through that array and collect your elements by ID.

That's the approach we've taken with ASP.NET apps with good success, though you may be doing something else. I would at least investigate the options jmbledsoe has described, they can help a little, but I doubt you'll get the performance you're hoping for.

Comment: Regarding the IDs, better yet may be to have identical IDs *except* for a numeric (or other unique) suffix. No need to maintain and loop through an array. Just use a "starts with" selector, as in `[id^=someID]` to get `someID1 someID2 someID3` etc.

Comment: Yea, it looks like this is what I'll end up doing. A shame since it's quite a hacky solution...

Answer (score 18):

Have a look at [jQuery: Performance analysis of selectors](https://sites.google.com/site/chandrasekhardutta/home/jquery-performance-analysis-of-selectors):

> ### Test 2 - Finding an element by Class
>
> Although CSS classes are intended to
> be reused among elements, you might
> create some elements with a unique
> class name just to identify and
> retrieve them through javascript. This
> is exactly what we test in this second
> test by seaching the element whose
> class is "p-4781". We have four
> alternatives:
>
> #### A - Using the class selector
>
> ```
> $('.p-4781').html()
> ```
>
> #### B - Using the class selector + tag
>
> ```
> $('p.p-4781').html()
> ```
>
> #### C - Using attribute search + tag
>
> ```
> $('p[class="p-4781"]').html()
> ```
>
> #### D - Using tag search + filter
>
> ```
> $('p').filter('.p-4781').html()
> ```
>
> After running this test for the first
> time in different browsers, I got:
>
> ```
>    Firefox Opera    IE6     IE7    Safari
> A     2891   641   1718     631      329
> B      453    78    313     180       78
> C      422   109    578     201      187
> D      203   266    375     210       94
> ```
>
> The table above shows case B as the
> fastest selector for most browsers
> (except Firefox). It is easy to
> understand why case A isn't efficient,
> since the code has to iterate over all
> elements of the DOM tree. Case C and D
> aren't that bad, but I would say case
> B should be the preferred one for this
> goal.

So use a tag name plus class name. It's way faster in older browsers.

Comment: Does jQuery perform any caching? If so, the order of the tests might be affecting the results.

Comment: @CurtainDog - It doesn't, it's really Sizzle not jQuery (which *includes* Sizzle) doing this part, you can view the source here:  http://github.com/jeresig/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help, but if your elements are all the same tag (e.g. DIV) you could use a selector like "DIV.classA". jQuery may be able to optimize that with a call to getElementsByTagName.

If you can specify a parent element, e.g. $('DIV.classA', someParent), that would limit the scope of what's being searched, which may increase performance.